# UITableView: Separating Datasource from TableViewController and assigning a #selector

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, ios10

I have the following setup:

A subclass of `UITableViewController` called: **`MainTVC`**

A datasource file called: **`MainDS`** that's a datasource to **`MainTVC`**

A cell class called: **`MainCell`**

**`MainCell`** has a UIButton called: `buttonMain`

`buttonMain` will assigned a `target` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in **`MainDS`** (Datasource file)

Code from **`MainDS`**:

```
....

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
               cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MainCell", for: indexPath) as! MainCell
    cell.buttonMain.addTarget(MainTVC(), action: #selector(MainTVC.buttonMainTapped(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    return cell
}
....
```

Nothing happens when `buttonMain` is tapped because `cell.buttonMain.addTarget(MainTVC()`.. <-  `#selector` needs the instance of `**MainTVC**` used by the MainDS.

It's my understanding that a datasource should NOT have an instance of its `ViewController`and thus, it shouldn't be passed in -- datasource just has access to the `tableView` of its `ViewController`.

Question:  What's the best practice of handling this?  How should I assign a `#selector` that's located in the `TableViewController` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` that's part of my Datasource file?

Comment: Don't invoke a method via #selector; use delegation or a closure

Answer (score 0):

In your MainDS, create  init function with parameter is an MainTVC  e.g:

```
class MainDS: UITableViewDataSource
 {
  weak var mainTVC:MainTVC?

  init(mainTVC: MainTVC) {
    self.mainTVC = mainTVC
  }
  ....

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
           cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MainCell", for: indexPath) as! MainCell
        cell.buttonMain.addTarget(self.mainTVC?, action: #selector(MainTVC.buttonMainTapped(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        return cell
   }
 ....
}
```

alloc MainDS in MainTVC

```
self.tableView.dataSource = MainDS(mainTVC: self)
```

Comment: Data source is not supposed to know about its controller.